# How to configure vim-latex to use portable MiKTeX to compile

Tags: vim, miktex

Recently I have installed `vim-latex` plugin in `gVim`. I use portable `MiKTeX` to compile `tex` document into `pdf` documents. Till now, I have used command prompt to compile the tex files. After installing `vim-latex` plugin I found that there's a compile option under `Tex-Suite>Compile` menu. But clicking it doesn't do anything. **So how can I configure vim-latex to use the portable MiKTeX compiler?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial googling let me to this link: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-compiling.html#Tex_CompileRule_format. However, I couldn't find any clue to where actually configure this variables. But finally I found the location. For my case it was

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\latex-suite\texrc
```

The **texrc** file has all the variables described in the link. As I said in my question, I use `miktex portable` so first I needed to change the compiler. So I searched for `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf` in the file and found this line

```
TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

So, I just replaced `pdflatex` with the full path

```
TexLet g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'E:\full\path\of\miktex\pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

Next thing that needed to be changed is telling vim-latex to use `pdflatex` to compile by default. So, I searched for the `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` variable in the file and found this line

```
if has('macunix')
    TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
else
    TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'dvi'
endif
```

No need to keep all this checking. so I commented out most of the lines

```
"if has('macunix')
    TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
"else
"   TexLet g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'dvi'
"endif
```

After this, vim-latex was able to compile my files. But the viewer wasn't working. So, needed to make a little more change. Searched for `g:Tex_ViewRule_ps` and changed the lines under `if has('win32')` to look like this.

```
if has('win32')
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'gsview32'
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'E:\Share\PortableApps\SumatraPDF-2.4\SumatraPDF.exe'
    TexLet g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'yap -1'
```

I had to use `SumatraPDF` because for some reason `Adobe Reader 11` was giving the error `Unable to find the file`. But `Sumatra` in not so bad. Now I can use vim-latex in peace :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a few variables in vim to configure vim-latex.

This one sets the order in which you want to export your tex file:

```
let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'
```

Notice that it converts the *.tex to *.dvi, then the *.dvi to *.ps, then *.ps to *.pdf.

The next ones you need to set are the compile rules for vim-latex.  Each of these rules define the program (and arguments) used to compile each output file:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_ps = 'dvips -Ppdf -o $*.ps $*.dvi'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'ps2pdf $*.ps'
```

When you convert from *.tex to *.dvi, vim-latex will use the 'latex' command.  Then, when it converts from *.dvi to *.ps, it will use dvips.  Finally it will use ps2pdf to convert from *.ps to *.pdf.

It looks like MikTex's executable is named 'latex', so you should be OK to use the above settings.  Just be sure that you have 'dvips' and 'ps2pdf' installed on your system.

The output *.pdf file will be in the directory which contains your source *.tex file.